# method returning either a collection or a single value

Tags: java, collections

I have a class with various properties and I would like to write a wrapper method around them in order to loop around them more easily.

Some properties return a **collection** of values, some a **single** value. And I'm looking for the best approach for this.

My first approach is to let the wrapper method return whatever the property getters return.

```
public class Test {

    public Object getValue(String propName) {
        if ("attr1".equals(propName)) return getAttribute1();
        else if ("attr2".equals(propName)) return getAttribute2();
        else return null;
    }

    public List<String> getAttribute1() {
        return Arrays.asList("Hello","World");
    }

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return "Goodbye";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Test test=new Test();

        Stream.of("attr1","attr2")
                .forEach(p-> {
                    Object o=test.getValue(p);
                    if (o instanceof Collection) {
                        ((Collection) o).forEach(v->System.out.println(v));
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(o);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

The bad point with this approach is that the caller has to test himself whether the result is a collection or not.

Other approach, seamless for the caller, is to always return a collection, ie. the wrapper function wraps the single values into a Collection. Here an HashSet, but we can imagine an adhoc, minimum 1 element list.

```
public class TestAlt {

    public Collection getValue(String propName) {
        if ("attr1".equals(propName))
            return getAttribute1();
        else if ("attr2".equals(propName)) {
            Set s = new HashSet();
            s.add(getAttribute2());
            return s;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    public List<String> getAttribute1() {
        return Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");
    }

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return "Goodbye";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final TestAlt test = new TestAlt();

        Stream.of("attr1", "attr2")
                .forEach(p -> {
                    test.getValue(p).forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));
                });
    }
```

Performance-wise, design-wise, ... what's your opinion on these approaches ? Do you have better ideas ?

Comment: Guess = can you have a collection with only one item in it?

Comment: Are you _just_ trying to print all the values? No other purposes? Also, will the type always be one of `List<String>` and `String`? Will there be other types like `int`?

Comment: @Marichyasana a collection with only one item is easily writable

Comment: @Sweeper It could be multiple types: String, Boolean, Number, ...And the purpose is to process them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could pass the action to be performed on each attribute to the object and let the object decide on how to handle it. E.g.:

in Class Test:

```
public void forEachAttribute(String propName, Handler h) {
    if ("attr1".equals(propName))
        h.handle(getAttribute1());
    else if ("attr2".equals(propName)) {
        getAttribute2().forEach(o -> h.handle(o))
    }
}
```

And a class `Handler` with the function `handle(String s)`, that does, what you want to do.

If you cannot edit `Test`, you can also move the function outside `Test`

```
public void forEachTestAttribute(Test t, String propName, Handler h)...
```

Performance-wise: This removes an if-clause

Design-wise: This removes a cast, but creates more classes.

*Edit: It also maintains type-security, and if there are multiple kinds of attributes (`String`, `int`, etc.) you could add more `handle`-functions, to still maintain type-security.

Comment: This could work if I didn't expect some result from the `Handler`... I could the replace 2 `Function` : one that performs the action and outputs some result, one that accumulates the the result of the `forEach`into one value... No so easy.

Comment: @lvr123 so you want the `handler.handle()` to produce some sort of result? One way of doing it, would be adding all of them into a `Collection`. Another way would be to put the code, that demands a result, into the `Handler` aswell, but I don't know if this is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the design I would rewrite your code into this:

**TestAlt.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestAlt {

    private Map<String, AttributeProcessor> map = AttributeMapFactory.createMap();

    public Collection getValue(String propName) {
        return Optional
            .ofNullable(map.get(propName))
            .map(AttributeProcessor::getAttribute)
            .orElse(Arrays.asList("default")); //to avoid unexpected NPE's 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final TestAlt test = new TestAlt();

        Stream.of("attr1", "attr2")
            .forEach(p -> test.getValue(p).forEach(v -> System.out.println(v)));
    }
}
```

**AttributeMapFactory.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AttributeMapFactory {

    public static Map<String, AttributeProcessor> createMap() {
        Map<String, AttributeProcessor> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("attr1", new HiAttributeProcessor());
        map.put("attr2", new ByeAttributeProcessor());
        return map;
    }
}
```

**AttributeProcessor.java**

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface AttributeProcessor {

    Collection<String> getAttribute();
}
```

**HiAttributeProcessor.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class HiAttributeProcessor implements AttributeProcessor{

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getAttribute() {
        return Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");
    }
}
```

**ByeAttributeProcessor.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ByeAttributeProcessor implements AttributeProcessor{

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getAttribute() {
        return Arrays.asList("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

The main point is that you get rid of if-else statements using map and dynamic dispatch.

The main advantage of this approach is that your code becomes more flexible to further changes. In case of this small programm it does not really matter and is an overkill. But if we are talking about large enterprise application, then yes, it becomes crucial.

Comment: Well, this is roughly the same approach as my TestAlt approach, where you encapsulate the single item attributes into a Collection (in your example, an ArrayList via Arrays.asList). The rest, I don't really understand how it could be more performant, as you create for each call of getValue both a map and arrays for each attributes. So if I have 10 attributes to loop through, you are creating 10 calls to getValue that creates 1 map + 10 lists: = 110 collections. While my TestAlt creates in the same conditions 10 collections.

Comment: I was focusing on design issues, not performance. But no doubt you are right: it is better not to create extra collections. You may initialize the map just once as a class variable of TestAlt. I will edit my answer accordingly. I would like to stress again: the design from my example is more preferable if you are dealing with constantly growing code base. It is easier to support, unit test and complement with new code. And it differs conceptually from your approach as I use polymorphism instead of if-else statements.